# Where are the Document types?

Tags: umbraco

I am new to umbraco and all I need to do is create a new template with a form.

What I understand so far is when I create a new page I choose a document type for the page which controls what template the site can use.

Now. First, there is a lot of Document types in "Settings -> Document Types". Some of them I am able to choose, but not all of them. I am also able to choose Document types not under "Document Types". Where are they? If I create a new Document type, I am not able to select it when creating a new page.

I have read som tutorials and documentations and they all say to just right click "Document Types" and create new then select it.

TLDR; I need to find a document type not visible under "Settings -> Document Types" so I can set the allowed templates. How do I find it?

Comment: What's the name of the document type you can not find in settings? Is this just your project or does someone else maintain it? Do you have administrative prilieges? Which version of umbraco are you using? Every document type has a tab _Structure_ where you can set allowed child document types, which is why you can not select your newly created document type.

Comment: This isn't really about programming is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you can see all document types, or you can see no document types. Aren't you mixing up with data types?

A basic tutorial on where to start can be found here: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/  Have tried this one?